# Determining weights for feedforward step in neural networks

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am following Prof. Andrew Ng's machine learning course on coursera. I have just completed programming assignment for week 5 which involved building a neural network for recognizing a digit in an image.

I am now trying to build an alphabet classifier. I am following the same homework tutorial for this purpose. Here is the tutorial:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/dszft60r8fftdio/ex4.pdf/file

The problem I am facing is at page 4 where it asks to compute cost function and states "You have been provided with a set of network parameters (Θ(1)
, Θ(2))
already trained by us."

I dont think I can use same set of weights for my purpose. So how you compute weights for feedforward step?

Comment: For convenience, here is the part that I am talking about.
https://i.imgur.com/SYVPYxb.jpg

Comment: Just keep doing the course, you will learn how to do it at some point. The entire point of that course is to teach you that